# sample space of experiment where We receive $1 each time a head comes up for ten successive coin tosses:

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Example 1.1. Consider two alternative games, both involving ten successive coin
tosses:
Game 1: We receive $1 each time a head comes up.

Now for this experiment the book mentions The sample space to be equal to 0, 1, . . . , 10
I can't understand how can this be the sample when the experiment clearly mentions ten successive coin from my understanding the sample space should be all sequences of H and T of length 10 and not just ten integers atleast to be consistent with sample space properties of being collectively exhaustive and mutually exclusive and then we should consider the event of atleast 1 head and calculate its probability

Comment: I think the sample space of coin tosses is $\{0H,1H,2H,…,10H\}$ where $nH$ means all the events in which $n$ heads and $10−n$ tails come up. For example- $3H$ means $\small HHHTTTTTTT,\:THHHTTTTTT,\:HTTHTHTTTT,… $ all $^{10}C_3$ possible combinations. Therefore the sample space of money received will be $\small\{\$0,\;\$1,\;\$2,\ldots,\$10\}$. Here the outcomes of sample space are not equally likely

Comment: You could use either sample space to model this situation.